# Setting httpVersion with httpClientBuilder

Tags: java, http, groovy

I have a httpClientBuilder instance,

I would like to set CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION to HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.

How should i set it with httpClientBuilder?

I have tried this:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1)
```

But this didn't seems to work.

Any help!

Comment: You are more likely to find help by adding a tag for the language in which your snippet is written. Is it Java?

Comment: Allow the instanciation of class HttpMethodParams and set the static field "PROTOCOL_VERSION" to HTTP_1_1.

Comment: @ludo_rj thanks for the hint, but can you share some code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just a sample code (in groovy) to improve my comment:

```
class MyHttpClientConfigurer implements org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpClientConfigurer {
         @Override
          void configureHttpClient(org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient client){
            client.params.setParameter(HttpClientParams.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1)
}
```

Comment: Hi @ludo_rj thanks for the code, but with apache-camel-http 2.13.1 snapshot.jar, configureHttpClient method takes HttpClientBuilder parameter not HttpClient, so do you know how could i set Protocol version with HttpClientBuilder.

Comment: It's even simpler, then use HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.getParams().setParameter(HttpClientParams.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

Comment: using new HttpClient() inside configureHttpClient method says 'HttpClient' is abstract, can't be instantiated.

Comment: Have you tried DefaultHttpClient ? Once you have the httpClient object created (by an inner method for instance), the only thing to do is to set the params with the static field described above.